# Webform Views - show results for host node id only

Tags: views, nodes, webforms

I'm using block webform on my site.

Is this possible to track submissions by host node ID (node, where user submitted the form)? Or the only way to achieve this is to add hidden field with current node ID and then sort it by this field?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look to this [hook_webform_submission_update](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_update/7) and let us know if it worked for you.